# how to get form values input in CSV through PHP

Tags: php, html, csv

I have written below code but it stores predefined input, my requirement is that user gives input and it gets stored in CSV.

I cannot use database for the same.

Where do I need to change in my code?

```
 <?php
 //read data from form
 $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
 $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
 $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
 $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone");

 //generate output for text file
 $output = $fName . "t";
 $output .= $lName . "t";
 $output .= $email . "t";
 $output .= $phone . "n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Follow my steps

1) Build a string by concatenating tab and newlines like below .

2) Open a file using `fopen` with append mode `"a"` (if file not exists it will create new one with you given name).

3) Write the file with your output string using `fwrite`.

4) Then close the file using `fclose`.

**form_page.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
     <form action="next_page.php" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="lName" />
      <input type="text" name="fName" />
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <input type="text" name="phone" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**next_page.php**

```
    <?php

     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {

     //read data from form
     $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
     $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
     $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone");

     //generate output for text file
     $output = $fName . "t";
     $output .= $lName . "t";
     $output .= $email . "t";
     $output .= $phone . "n";

     //here "t" means tab
     //here "n" newline 

     //open file for output with append mode "a"
     $fp = fopen("contacts.csv", "a");
     //write to the file
     fwrite($fp, $output);
     fclose($fp);

    }
    else
    {
       echo "empty submit";
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: i want the user to input details in html form but receive output in csv.

Comment: you just create html form @JayantKaushik

Comment: the only issue i have now is that the form inputs are in single cell in the CSV that is being generated. HELP!!

Comment: use "\t"; insted of "t";  and "\n";  insted of "n"; @JayantKaushik

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
<?php

$lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
$fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
$phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone");

$output = $fName . "t";
$output .= $lName . "t";
$output .= $email . "t";
$output .= $phone . "n";

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $output);

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: i want the user to input details in html form but receive output in csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'lName' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
    'fName' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
    'email' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
    'phone' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone");
);

$file = fopen('file.csv','w+');
fputcsv($file, $arr);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: i want the user to input details in html form but receive output in csv.